# Copy data from local to production

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 copies of database, one on local PC other on production server (web site). I insert data into my local copy. How can I upload the newly inserted data (in local-copy) to production server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an incremental backup and restore it on prod.

Or use Import/Export Wizard if you can gather the new data using several queries.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you generate insert scripts and then run them on the prod server.

There are many tools to do this: a popular one is [RedGate SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/).

Answer (score 0):

Add the other machine as a "Linked Server" under "Server Objects".

Then access it like:

```
SELECT * FROM ServerPotato.DB_AWE.dbo.potato_prices
```

which is:

```
<Linked Server>.<Database>.<Schema Owner>.<Table>
```

The schema `dbo` is probably necessary, where normally you may write: `DB_AWE..potato_prices`

Comment: Where to find Server Objects? I am using SQL 2008 Express with Management Studio.